# How to add an ExpandableListadApter in a MergeAdapter from cwac

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am using the MergeAdapter from:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

I want to add an ExpandableListadApter to the MergeAdapter but it currently takes in a type 'ListAdapter'.  Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: @ CLDev did you find the solution? Currently me too need this plz let me know if you find the Answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539400/how-to-show-all-list-items-in-child-listview-using-cwac-merge-1-0-4-jar

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `MergeAdapter` only supports the `ListAdapter` interface. Aside from forking the repo and adding support for the `ExpandableListAdapter`, there's really only one other way I think you could "hack" a quick solution.

Android uses an `ExpandableListConnector` to map an `ExpandableListAdapter` to a `BaseAdapter`.  You could literally copy that class over to your project, and instantiate it with your `ExpandableListAdapter`. That'll give you a `ListAdapter` compliant adapter you can use with the `MergeAdapter`.

Note, I've never tried this...but theoretically it should work.

[ExpandableListConnector source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/ExpandableListConnector.java#ExpandableListConnector.%3Cinit%3E%28android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter%29)