# How to show All list items in child ListView-using cwac-merge-1.0.4 jar

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, commonsware-cwac

I am using two ListView in same screen,Because of using two `Listviews` likely `Parent ListView` and `Child ListView`,that  Child ListView `Adapter` class doesn't show all List Values in Child ListView.It showed only `0 th(first)` position in Child ListView,for this above issue I have used the answer code from this [Android list view inside a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view) link.now I can see all list values in my `Child ListView` but It is not showing all my List values in same time which I had grabbed from `Web service call`.It showed first value only in list because the List View height was set to list's single item height.If I scroll down the Child ListView I am able to see all values in ListView.What I need is If i get five list values from Web service It has to show all five items in same time.

**note:** If I set hard coded values for List,It showed all items in Child ListView at one time.

**Edited**

**How I achieved it using MergeAdapter**

This `createAdapter` method  would return `Adapter` object and I have set that Adapter into my Listview using `setAdapter(createAdapter(new ArrayList<T>()))`

```
 private ListAdapter createAdapter(List<T> items) {

        mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();
        mergeAdapter.addAdapter(endlessFeedAdapter);       

        return  mergeAdapter;
    }
```

**What I need is**

I Have been suggested to use `ExpandableListView` instead of using `two ListViews`.
If I use `ExpandableListView` I will have to change the `createAdapter` method return type into `ExpandableListAdapter` for this I used below code

```
 private ExpandableListAdapter createAdapter(List<T> items) {

            mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();
            mergeAdapter.addAdapter(endlessFeedAdapter);       

            return (ExpandableListAdapter) mergeAdapter;
        }
```

but it showed the below `Excaption`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.commonsware.cwac.merge.MergeAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter`
Values from Web service

[image]
[image]

Hard coded values

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding your setup correctly, I think you should be using an ExpandableListView, instead of trying to nest ListViews.

Comment: I had completed all my required things using these two `ListViews`.If I migrate to `ExpandableListView`  it would take more time for implementation.according to my point of view any small changes in code will fix this.

Comment: You are fighting an uphill battle man. Embedding two ListView's together does not work well with Android. It's a big no no. You should be using an `ExpandableListView`.  Also, it's a huge performance hit when you embed an adapter inside another adapter. It may be a pain to migrate but that's the way to go. Otherwise, you'll just continue to hack up the code to get something to work that wasn't designed to work like that.

Comment: Just remove all this "code" what you have done, and start from zero with any tutorial from internet, e.g. http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/

Comment: My apologies for not responding to this sooner -- I did not get an email notification for it. I agree with the above comments, that having a `ListView` inside of a `ListView` is unlikely to work well. With regards to your `ClassCastException`, `MergeAdapter` is not an `ExpandableListAdapter`. You will need to implement your own `ExpandableListAdapter` -- see [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/ExpandableListView) for an example of this.

Comment: Once you get the data from the web service call, calculate the number of rows you need and programmatically set the height of the child ListView to be number of rows * height of one row. I can give you sample code if this is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is stopping you to make 2 different adapters and adding them to MergeAdapter? You can add multiple adapters to MergeAdapter and multiple views. In that case there is no need to use 2 Listviews.

```
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapterHeading);
mergeAdapter.addView(someView);
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapterFooter);
listView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
```